# is there a smaple quarkus project with multiple named OidcClients to call multiple service calls?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-oidc

am looking for a sample quarkus reactive project with multiple OidcClients to make multiple service calls?

Eg: DemoProject wants to call service A, B, C, D.
DemoProject used keycloak authorization with grant type as password.
Service A has OidcClientA, service B has OidcClientB, service C has OidcClientC, Service D has OidcClientD.
How can we simply inject OidcClient into a specific service and fetching the specific token, authorization header to a specific service automatically?

Quarkus Documentation: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-client

Comment: Please, do not use edits as comments, its better to post the information as a comment or edit you own question with updates on what you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried the non filter approach?, to check if this works

Answer (score 1):

This is completely possible, and actually very easy.
The problem is that is not properly documented; i had to dig into quarkus source code to find it.

In your application.properties, just add the client-name you want after quarkus.oidc-client.

For example, before named client:

```
quarkus.oidc-client.auth-server-url=<url>
```

Will then become

```
quarkus.oidc-client.<client-name>.auth-server-url=<url>
```

Then in the code, where Tokens or OidcClient is injected, just add @NamedOidcClient("").

And that's it!

I will post with a working git later.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any sample project, but i think that you just need to configure the named clients in your properties files and they will be accesible through the `OidcClients` class.

[Here](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-client#oidcclients) you can find more information.

If you are going to consume each service individually I would suggest you create a facade or a service in front of the rest client to deal with this complexity or maybe a filter for each service rest-client